# Redux Toolkit — can't update initial state that equals null

Tags: typescript, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit, redux-persist

Got strange behavior using Redux Toolkit with Redux Persist. I can't update user's initial state if it's null. This code always sets null to the store regrdless of passing params.

```
import { createSlice, PayloadAction } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { IUser, Nullable } from "../../types";

const initialState = null as Nullable<IUser>  

export const userSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'user',
    initialState: initialState,
    reducers: {
        set(state, action: PayloadAction<IUser>){
            state = action.payload
        }
    }
})

export default userSlice.reducer;
```

But, if initial state looks like below all works fine. I am wondering why.

```
const initialState = {
    user: null as Nullable<IUser>  
}
```

Comment: Any luck here? I'm having the same issue. Mine is a bit different because I'm using an array of users, but maybe it's the same idea.

Comment: @dmathisen Gave up trying to find the cause of this behavior. Added my solution below, check it.

Comment: Gotcha. Thank you. I think we had different issues. Mine was resolved by adding a CaseReducer type (answer found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72185403/1308734)

Answer (score 0):

Because that's how it's implemented, meaning that if the initial state is a reference type/object, all the following states must be too. Likewise if the initial state is a primitive type/null the following state(s) must be of primitive type.

When dealing with an initially and occasionally undefined/null object, I usually do it like this:

```js
import {
  createSlice
} from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: "user",
  initialState: {
    value: undefined
  },
  reducers: {
    setUser: (state, action) => {
      state.value = action.payload;
    },
  },
});

export const { setUser } = userSlice.actions;

export const userReducer = userSlice.reducer;
```

Answer (score -1):

Finally did this. Don't know if it is a proper solution

```
import { createSlice, PayloadAction } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { Nullable, User } from "../../../types";

const initialState = null as Nullable<User>;

export const userSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'user',
    initialState: initialState,
    reducers: {
        set(state, action: PayloadAction<User>){
            return state ? {...state, ...action.payload} :  action.payload;
        },
        setToken(state, action: PayloadAction<User['token']>){
            state && (state.token = action.payload)
        },
        setUsername(state, action: PayloadAction<User['username']>){
            state && (state.username = action.payload)
        },
        unset(){
            return initialState
        }
    }
})

export default userSlice.reducer;
```