# Is is possible to use an typescript Union type for the state of a Redux Toolkit Slice?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux-toolkit

I'd like to use an union type like this to represent my slice's state when using Redux Toolkit:

```js
type AppState = { loading: true } | { loading: false; data: number };
```

It seems like the usage of Immerjs in the reducer files prevents me from switching between the two Union options, e.g.:

```js
import { createSlice, PayloadAction } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState: AppState = { loading: true };

export const sampleSlice = createSlice({
  name: "sample",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setup: (state) => {
      return { loading: false, data: 5 };
    },
  },
});
```

Which gives me the following Typescript error:

```
Type '(state: WritableDraft<{ loading: true; }>) => { loading: false; data: number; }' is not assignable to type 'CaseReducer<{ loading: true; }, { payload: any; type: string; }> | CaseReducerWithPrepare<{ loading: true; }, PayloadAction<any, string, any, any>>'.
```

Is there any way to make this work? My current workaround is not using an union type to represent the state but I'm wondering if there is a workaround. I have also tried not using booleans but string literals for the `loading` key but it produces the same error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**NOTE:** Per the docs, Option 2 is the better approach.

**Option 1**. Provide the generic parameter types for `createSlice`.

```
import { createSlice, SliceCaseReducers } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

type AppState = { loading: true } | { loading: false; data: number };

const initialState: AppState = { loading: true };

type CaseReducers = SliceCaseReducers<AppState>;

export const sampleSlice = createSlice<AppState, CaseReducers>({
  name: 'sample',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setup: (state) => {
      return { loading: false, data: 5 };
    },
  },
});
```

The `state` type in case reducer:

[image]

**Option 2.** Cast the initial state. See [Defining the Initial State Type](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript#defining-the-initial-state-type)

```
import { createSlice, SliceCaseReducers } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

type AppState = { loading: true } | { loading: false; data: number };

const initialState: AppState = { loading: true };

// type CaseReducers = SliceCaseReducers<AppState>;

export const sampleSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'sample',
  initialState: initialState as AppState,
  reducers: {
    setup: (state) => {
      return { loading: false, data: 5 };
    },
  },
});
```

package versions:

```json
"@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.6.1",
"typescript": "^4.3.5",
```

Comment: Please don't do option 1. `createSlice` should never be called with a manual generic annotation. That will remove all info about actions in there. Source: I wrote the types for it.
Option 2 is the recommendation from our docs.

Comment: Thank you so much!
Went with option number 2